# Inverted transistor function

Tags: transistors

Looking for some help on components/circuitry that can very quickly make an open circuit in a digital wire (eg. LIN or CAN).

I’m working as an automotive trainer and would like to create an open in a wire to simulate an intermittent connection fault. The signal wire sending data packages should pass through a “Normally Closed” component.

Using a pulse generator I can send a short 5 V (milliseconds) pulse that should create an OPEN in the actual signal wire.

A mechanical relay is way too slow, so some form of transistor must be used.

Any tips?

Comment: Why is a relay too slow? I believe relays can be purchased that routinely provide 3 ms switching. Since you are willing to provide 5 ms pulses, that should be fine I would imagine.

Comment: [Here's a solid state relay for automotive use](https://www.e-t-a.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Ordnerstruktur/pdf-Data/Products/Relais/Halbleiterrelais/2_eng/D_ESR10_Micro_ENG.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need switching faster than a relay (and as @jonk points out, you can get relatively fast relays) you probably want an SSR like [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ixys-integrated-circuits-division/CPC1017NTR/655290) which will give you sub-ms switching (depending on the conditions). This is just one I have used in the past, you can search for others which may be faster, and a better fit to your specific use case (blocking voltage, capacitance, max current, etc)